# Single login window for administrator as well as users

Tags: php, this, login-control

Please tell me the PHP code to make a login code for user as well as admin through a single login control.

I am using the following code but I think that it is not the right way to do this...

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="id"/>
<input type="password" name="pswd"/>
<input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) {
 ob_start();
 $id=$_POST['id'];
 $pswd=$_POST['pswd'];

 $sql="SELECT * FROM admin WHERE id=........."
 $query=mysql_query($sql);
 $count=mysql_num_rows($query);
 if($count==1) {
  header('location: admin/index.php');
 } else {
  $sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=........."
  $query=mysql_query($sql);
  $count=mysql_num_rows($query);
  if($count==1) {
   header('location: user/index.php');
  } else {
  echo 'Invalid id-password combination';
 }
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it shorter with one query if thats's what you need.

```
<form action="" method="post">
..........
</form>

<?php

    if( isset($_POST['submit'] ) ) {
        $result = mysql_fetch_array( "SELECT user.*, \"user\" as t FROM user WHERE id=".$_POST['id']." UNION SELECT admin.*, \"admin\" as t WHERE id=".$_POST['id']." FROM admin" );
        if( is_array( $result) ) foreach( $result as $i ) {
            if( $i['id']==$_POST['id'] && $i['passwd']==$_POST['passwd'] ) {
                // also here you should set cookie to be checked in user/index.php and admin/index.php to prevent user to get into admin space by directly typing the url
                if( $i['t']=="admin" ) {
                    header('location: admin/index.php');
                } else {
                    header('location: user/index.php');
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    echo( "Invalid id-password combination" );

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work too, however you need to follow some kind of convention, like admin user-id must starts with admin, say admin_XXX and user can't use admin in their user-id and thus you can filter those while validating login form.

Comment: There is one problem in this case that if the user types admin's url in address bar of explorer then he can enter admin's panel...which is strictly wrong...

Comment: you can't allow to access admin panel just by entering url, system must validate user session and current user must get page he has assess to else redirect to some generic page or show appropriate msg for the same.
it's totally what suites your pattern of programming, it must be logical no matter how you implement it, unless it works and convenient for programmer. hope it make sense!

Answer (score 0):

First, you should validate the `$_POST`-Data as it comes from the user. You do not know if someone wants to mess with your DB (read here for more information: http://php.net/manual/de/security.database.sql-injection.php).

After you are sure, the input is not malicious you can send the query to your DB. I assume, that you opened a correct connection to your MySQL-DB?! If so, the first call is
`$query = mysql_query($sql);` instead of `$query=mysql_fetch_array($sql);`.

Further you should set information about the users login state in the session. If you do not, you can not determine wether the user is logged in or not.

And if you can not determine that there is no sense in checking the username before you deliver the admin or the user page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...I got what you said...but my question is that the user is able to go to the admin panel by changing url after successful login through his id and password

Comment: This is why I mentioned the session. You should read about PHP sessions [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php). When your login validates the user as admin you can store this information in the session, e.g. `$_SESSION['admin] = true;`.  In you other pages you have to query this information from the session and restrict access if the user is not allows to see the content. `if ($_SESSION['admin] != true) header("Location: /login.php");`

Answer (score 0):

The simpler solution is to have all users in a single table, and give them rights with levels. For example admin is usually level 0 (or having a flag called root or something), and a simple user level 1.

So when you do your login submit, the code will check something like this:

```
// $db is your mysql connection
$user = array();
if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
 $sql = "SELECT id, level FROM users WHERE username='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])."' AND password=MD5('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password'])."'";
 $rs = mysql_query($sql, $db);
 if (mysql_num_rows($rs)>0) {
  $user['username'] = $_POST['username'];
  $user['login_time'] = time();
  // user found, let's see his rights
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
   $rights = $row['level'];
   $user['id'] = $row['id']; // keep the id for references
   if ($rights = 0) {
     $user['admin'] = true; // is admin
   } else {
     $user['admin'] = false; // is normal user
   }
  }
  // user array is now full of the data we want, so put it in a session, cookie
  // or anything else and then go to login area or whatever.
  header("location: /login-area.php");
 } else { 
   header("location: /user-login-failed.php"); // Send him to a user not found page
 }
} else {
  // The post here is empty. Someone is trying to do something or something went really 
  // wrong. It's up to you.
}
```